# Constants Local to Member Functions

Tags: python, class, closures, constants, member-functions

I am looking for a good solution for where to put (semantic) constants inside a class that are only relevant to some specific member function. I don't want to initialize these constants every time I call the member function, but I also do not want to clog up the class with them:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        # possible class related constants here
        self.func_constant = some_value # meh, does not belong here

    def func(self):
        func_constant = some_value # ... no, that is inefficient
```

If this was in the context of free functions, I would use a closure:

```
def make_func():
    constant = some_value
    def func():
        #code
    return func

func = make_func()
```

I don't know of a way to declare member functions as the return value of a closure though. I mean I could do this:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        # possible class related constants here
        self.func = make_func()
```

But that is bad design for a whole different set of reasons, and might not even work, if `func` needs to access other members of `C`.

Therefore, my question: Is there a way to have member function local constants, that are only initialized once, rather than every function call.

Comment: "but I also do not want to clog up the class with them" - why not? The class seems like a perfectly reasonable place to put them. Your example is storing it on each instance for some reason, though.

Comment: No particular reason why per instance. It might be a constant for a specific instance, but inside the instance only relevant to one function. And well, the reason, as I described, is clean semantic separation. An example might me stride length for a function `walk` of a class `Animal`, where the stride length is determined by the animal's height. I would want `stride_length` to be computed ONCE, when the instance is created, but at the same time be local to the only function it has to do with.

Comment: stick a container on your instance, like a dict, and use that as a namespace, or a name-space of namespaces (a dict of dicts, i.e. from method-name to it's "personal", per-instance namespace). You can probably use all sorts of meta-class sorcery to make this seem magical, but using a container seems the most reasonable. Or better yet, *just use the instance namespace*. That is what it is for. If you are expecting name-clashes, then maybe these member functions should be objects of their own type instead

Comment: @lotolmencre fundamentally, the OOP paradigm doesn't really do corner off state per member function, the whole point is you share state with the whole isntance. but nothing is stopping you from using another paradigm in Python.

Comment: You might consider using a `mixin` for each function that has such variables (if that makes sense for the particular class and function). Then the variables can be defined relative to the `mixin` rather than the main class.